# How to make an IEqualityComparer for (int*int) [] doing structural comparison?

Tags: .net, f#, comparison

I want to make a `hashset` of `(int*int)[]`, so as following

```
let mySet = new HashSet<_>()
```

because I thought the default comparer for `array` and `tuple` is `HashIdentity.Structural`, it would auto satisfy my needs.

However it doesn't work. Here is my experiment:

```
let mySet = new HashSet<_>()
let a = [|1;2|]
let b = [|1;2|]
let c = compare a b
mySet.Add(a)
mySet.Add(b)

val a : int [] = [|1; 2|]
val b : int [] = [|1; 2|]
val c : int = 0
val it : HashSet<int []> = seq [[|1; 2|]; [|1; 2|]]

let mySet = new HashSet<_>()
let a = [1;2]
let b = [1;2]
let c = compare a b
mySet.Add(a)
mySet.Add(b)

val a : int list = [1; 2]
val b : int list = [1; 2]
val c : int = 0
val it : HashSet<int list> = seq [[1; 2]]
```

As we can see that the default `IEqualityComparer` for *array* is not `HashIdentity.Structural`, but *list* is. However the default `IComparer` is structural for both of them.

That's a bit strange, any reason why? Also how to make an `IEqualityComparer` for my hashset by using the default structural comparison of `tuple` and `array`.

I know how to do it manually in C#, but since I just started to learn F#, can anyone help?

The following code is my effort:

```
let a = [|(1,2);(2,3)|]
let b = [|(1,2);(2,3)|]

type MyEqualityComparer() =
    interface IEqualityComparer<(int*int)[]> with
        member this.Equals (a,b) = (Array.forall2 (=) a b)
        member this.GetHashCode (a) = hash (a |> Array.map hash)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think one reason is that Array is a mutable and .NET-compatible type. It makes sense to follow *reference comparison* which is default in .NET framework.

You can pass `HashIdentity.Structural` as an argument. The following example uses structural comparison on arrays and tuples:

```
let mySet = HashSet(HashIdentity.Structural)
let a = [|(1, 2)|]
let b = [|(1, 2)|]
mySet.Add(a)
mySet.Add(b)
// val it : HashSet<(int * int) []> = seq [[|(1, 2)|]]
```

Answer (score 2):

check the documentation for [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90.aspx) and [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495294.aspx) classes.

**HashSet**

*Initializes a new instance of the HashSet class that is empty and uses the default equality comparer for the set type.*

**Dictionary**

*Every key in a Dictionary must be unique according to the default equality comparer.
Dictionary requires an equality implementation to determine whether keys are equal. This constructor uses the default generic equality comparer, EqualityComparer.Default. If type TKey implements the System.IEquatable generic interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation. Alternatively, you can specify an implementation of the IEqualityComparer generic interface by using a constructor that accepts a comparer parameter.*