# IEqualityComparer instance for two-dimensional arrays

Tags: dictionary, f#, hashset, iequalitycomparer, structural-equality

F# supports structural equality of two-dimensional arrays with the `=` operator, and in F# collections such as `Set`. But how can I use the same equality comparison in the .NET class `HashSet`? By default it uses referential equality, and although there is a constructor that takes an instance of `IEqualityComparer<T>` I cannot find a suitable built-in instance for two-dimensional arrays.

I looked at `System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer`, but that seems to have two problems. Firstly, it is not generic, and secondly, it does not seem to support two-dimensional arrays:

```
> let xss = Array2D.create 2 2 99;;
> let yss = Array2D.create 2 2 99;;

// `=` operator does what I want
> xss = yss;;
val it : bool = true

// pre-defined StructuralEqualityComparer object doesn't work
> open System.Collections;;
> let comp = StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer;;
val comp : IEqualityComparer
> (xss :> IStructuralEquatable).Equals(yss, comp);;
System.ArgumentException: Array was not a one-dimensional array.
   at System.Array.GetValue(Int32 index)
   at System.Array.System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable.Equals(Object other, IEqualityComparer comparer)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0023>.$FSI_0023.main@()
```

Ultimately, I'd like to fix the following code so that it returns 1, not 2:

```
> let hashset = new Generic.HashSet<int[,]>();;
> hashset.Add xss;;
> hashset.Add yss;;
> hashset.Count;;
val it : int = 2
```

I would also be happy with a solution using `Dictionary`, but I think the same issues apply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an IEqualityComparer for (int\*int) \[\] doing structural comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586814/how-to-make-an-iequalitycomparer-for-intint-doing-structural-comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let a = Array2D.create 2 2 99
let b = Array2D.create 2 2 99
let set = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet(HashIdentity.Structural)
set.Add a
set.Add b
printfn "%A" set.Count // 1
```

<sub>[Online demo](http://ideone.com/9kQUEs)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little amused that HashSet made it into .NET core while HashIdentity didn't (though perhaps it's safer that way, given that arrays are mutable).